# Can't get data from a composable using destructuring in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup, composable

I'm trying to get books data from firebase in the Vue component (Book.vue). It works fine when I write a the function inside the component.

But it doesn't work when I try to convert it into a composable.

Althought the console isn't showing any error, but still the page isn't displaying any data.

> This code works (when showBooks is used as a function)

**Book.vue**

```
<template>
  <!-- books list -->
  <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="book">
    <span class="material-icons"> favorite </span>
    <h2>{{ book.title }}</h2>
    <div>
      <span class="material-icons"> done </span>
      <span class="material-icons"> edit </span>
      <span class="material-icons"> delete </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/config";
import { onMounted } from "@vue/runtime-core";

const books = ref([]);

async function showBooks() {


  const colRef = collection(db, "books");

  const docs = await getDocs(colRef);
  docs.forEach((doc) => {
    const book = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
    books.value.push(book);
  });
}
onMounted(() => {
  showBooks();
});
</script>
```

> This doesn't work. (when showBooks is used inside a composable)

**getBooks.js (composable)**

```
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/config";


async function showBooks() {
    const books = ref([]);
    const colRef = collection(db, "books");

    const docs = await getDocs(colRef);
    docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const book = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
        books.value.push(book);
    });


    return { books }
}


export { showBooks }
```

**Books.vue**

```
<template>
  <!-- books list -->
  <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="book">
    <span class="material-icons"> favorite </span>
    <h2>{{ book.title }}</h2>
    <div>
      <span class="material-icons"> done </span>
      <span class="material-icons"> edit </span>
      <span class="material-icons"> delete </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { onMounted } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import { showBooks } from "../use/getBooks.js";

const { books } = showBooks();

onMounted(() => {
  showBooks();
});
</script>
```

Comment: "This code works (when showBooks is used as a function)" - it cannot. `books` is available only inside showBooks function. You could possibly mix these snippets up, but the problem statement needs to be clear

Comment: Oh my bad.  I actually used that outside of the function which works. But it still doesn't work for the composable(even if I use it outside of the function inside the composable).

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce it. Should behave the same way without firebase. I don't see why these snippets should behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple things going wrong here, but you're close.

1. In the Book.vue that's working you define books like so `const books = ref([]);`. That's great continue to do that instead of defining it like this `const { books } = showBooks();`. This latter way you're not using `ref` so your template won't be reactive with books and you're not `await`ing the result.
2. Then update your mounted hook to await the promise and assign the value to your books ref. `onMounted(async () => { let data = await showBooks(); books.value = data.books; });`